# Why do I need to do a Git Remote Update to both push and pull my changes?

Tags: git

I started a new project recently and spend the day programming at the library on my laptop and at night I use my desktop at home. I decided to give Git a try but didn't see the need to host it on a public server so I decided to go the google drive route and followed [these instructions](http://kahthong.com/2012/05/how-use-google-drive-or-dropbox-host-your-private-git-repositories). Once both my laptop and desktop were set up I started working on my laptop and when I was done I did the git adds, commit, and push and saw my google drive sync to completion. When I got home I saw google drive sync up and I tried doing a git pull but it kept saying it was already up to date. I deleted the repo and retried the entire process several times and could not get this to work and also kept running into this message "There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify which branch you want to merge with". I had no other branches, I just want to make changes on whatever machine I'm on, commit and push those changes, and jump on my other machine and pull those changes so I can keep working. In desperation I would just delete my local clone and re-clone and presto, everything was there again. I re-read the Git book but didn't find anything that I could use. Finally I stumbled on someone's comment to some article somewhere saying to try "git remote update" to get it to work if you couldn't get your latest changes so I tried that and then tried a pull but nothing happened. I struggled some more for a couple of days, deleting and recreating the repo and trying all sorts of things until finally something I did worked. When I looked back at what I did I saw that I had to do a "git remote update" *after* my push and once I got home to my desktop I had to do a "git remote update" *before* I did a pull. This is not mentioned anywhere and so far all the git documentation I've read made it seem that it was as simple as doing a push and a pull; there's no mention whatsoever of "git remote update". Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> I can imagine many ways how this will end in total chaos, so I strongly advise against this way of sharing a repository.  Just put it on GitHub or Bitbucket.

You are not going to do `git pull`, `git fetch` or `git push` **ever** if you use Google Drive to keep your repository in more than one place.

The repository you have in Google Drive is a *local repository* on each of the machines that you sync it to, for all intents and purposes (assuming you put the checked out working copy into Google Drive as well).

Every repository operation will be reflected verbatim on all the machines that you sync your Google Drive directory with.  There are no "remotes" and **none of the Git operations that deal with "remotes" apply in your case**.

**Update for clarification:** what I said above does not apply to the blog post that you referenced, since they advise you to create a *bare repository*, and sync that via Google Drive (that's a bad idea as well, read below).

If you put a "bare repository" on Google Drive (which does not include a checked out version, or working copy), then you will have to **clone that bare repository** on each machine where you sync to, and then the local version of the bare repository is the remote (in this case, you will use "remote" operations, but they'll all work with a local copy of a shared bare repository).

Each machine then has their own, local version, of a shared remote; Google Drive merely makes sure that this is reflected across machines.

Comment: Or bitbucket if you want free private repos.

Comment: I don't understand why this is an issue. Google Drive acts as a shared drive or remote server to each of my machines for all intents and purposes; as long as I make sure everything is synced before I do any operation I should be good to go. So I have a bare repository on the google drive and I do a clone on my local directory on each of my machines (let's say /C/Dev/MyProject). I imagine I would need to pull/push between my local (/C/Dev/MyProject) and google drive "remote" repository, no?

Comment: IF you make sure everything is shared and there will never be conflicts, then this approach will work.  And that is a very big IF.  When you get conflicts (that is just a matter of time), it will be impossible to reconcile them without losing changes to the repository.

Comment: Right, it should work so long as I keep everything in sync which isn't that hard to do. Your answer, however, did not answer my question. I'm not asking whether Google Drive is the appropriate platform for my git repository; I'm asking why do I have to do a Git Remote Update for both push and pulls given the relative simplicity of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Upvoted Sigi's answer for being very informative and clearly expressing the issues with your current solution. To directly answer your question of "Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?", yes, we can. What you're doing wrong is using Google Drive as a remote git repository. Mike D's suggestion to use Bitbucket would provide you with better results (free unlimited number of private repositories for projects with < 5 people, and it seems like it's just you).

Comment: @Noah The question "Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?" does not pertain to my choice of girlfriend, dog, or choice of Google Drive as a host for my repository; that's not what I'm asking and none of them are relevant to the question or the issue. If you believe Google Drive to be my issue then support your claim with some facts and evidence rather than just saying "it's wrong".

Comment: The article you linked has comments where the author admits "This tutorial with Google Drive thingy was more of a personal backup of your own Git repositories. Its quite inconvenient." Sigi has already gone through a fairly comprehensive list of the drawbacks and sticking points.

Comment: @Noah So in other words you have no facts or evidence to substantiate your claim. As for Sigi he has already commented that this approach will work if I'm careful, which I am. However, I already know that this approach works for me; whether it's inconvenient or not is up to me to decide. I am looking for an answer to a different question totally unrelated to my choice of host, and if it so happens that it *is* my choice of host then I would like an actual answer rather than "your problem is that you purchased a Yugo; you should purchase a BMW instead" which is pretty useless.

Comment: You're using a screwdriver handle to pound a nail into the wall, and saying I can't provide proof that you're not using the right tool, when I'm handing you a hammer. Sure, your solution will get the nail driven into the wall, but it's a whole lot easier to use (and get support for) proper tool usage. Using Google Drive to sync a repository will certainly work, but it's an unsupported (from a git standpoint) and glitchy solution, and you can't reasonably expect people to debug your problems. Try the hammer.

Comment: @Noah Yes, I saw that link, but unlike him I found a way to make it work. What I would like to know is why it doesn't work without making the call to "Git Remote Update". If I make that call then all is well, but I'd like to know why.

Comment: @Anthony Please write an article on your blog after you've lost three days of work due to following this approach.

Comment: @Sigi I don't have a blog but I described my solution when I asked the question so it's available to everyone. Also, I never lost any work at all since I had my local copy. What I lost was an hour each day trying to figure out what I was doing wrong; my persistence paid off but I'd love to know what's wrong since I can't imagine why, from a technical perspective, Google Drive would have anything to do with it; it's just a synchronization service after all which simply produces identical copies of files. The only difference I can think of is timestamp; if git depends on this then its a problem

Comment: @Sigi Thanks for the constructive advice; that along with your "answer" and its associated comments go a long way towards helping answer my question. I am one step closer to understanding why I need to issue a "Git Remote Update".